# Geometry header in css

Tags: css, header, web, geometry

i'm working on my personal website and i have an idea. Better it will show as a image.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d719U.png)

I want to ask how to do the geometry in the header only with css. It must always be the center of the page. Logo could be fixed at the center of the header. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've never worked with SVG but i will check it.

Comment: What part of that image do you need to create?

Comment: I neee create header of site.

Comment: You mean [THIS](http://s25.postimg.org/j505bk6fj/Untitled.png) part as a header?

Comment: Ye this is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Analysing the design shows it is mostly made up of a lot of triangular shapes, plus three boxes. You can therefore do the whole thing with CSS. The way to create a triangle in CSS is to use a div, give it zero width and height, and a border of a suitable thickness. There are many articles on the web on how to do this, and it has been explained before on StackOverflow as well, with some excellent explanations of the theory behind it.

So there's a lot out there to consult and I won't go into it again at length here. But basically the CSS is like:

```
.triangle {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-bottom: 100px solid blue; 
    border-left: 50px solid green; 
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
```

This particular example produces a right angled triangle with one side sloping in the direction of the main diagonal in your design - i.e. from bottom-left to top-right. Making border-left and border-bottom the same length would produce a diagonal at 45 degrees, but in your design it's a different angle, so I've used different lengths. You can experiment to get exactly the slope you want. Whether you use border left, right, bottom, or top decides the orientation of the triangle.

Having achieved that main diagonal, identify the other triangles in the design and create some more, smaller divs and add similar CSS. You can then overlay them on top of the design using absolute positioning, and a bit of z-index if needed. One bit of the stuff in the center will also need a tiny rectangular div putting on top of the triangles.

It's as neat an exercise in CSS triangles as ever I've seen, but I'll leave you to work out the details!

Comment: Do you think that this could be done so that it was still at the center of the head? I wanted a logo centered in the middle.

Comment: Yes. You'll want to put the whole design into a container div anyway, with a width and height to give it the right size. Having done that just give that div `margin : 0 auto` (or `margin : Npx auto` if you want a margin between the top of the page and the top side of your design).